# retrive tweets in real time and send emails with the tweet text

Tags: php, api, twitter, oauth, real-time

like most of the support systems like zendesk do, I need a way to send email for every new tweet with the tweet in it.

In Zendesk we can attach twitter account, so every tweet on that account will be turned as support ticket, so it is possible to retrieve them in real time or twitter post any http request to a specific URL on every tweet?

Comment: any one with this need?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve ?

If you need to allow users to attach a twitter account to a system your end and have every mention of that user to a new support ticket, it is indeed possible. You will need to look at the Twitter API docs.

https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation

Specifically look at the mentions_timeline. From here for each tweet you look at for the specific user you could create a new ticket. You could further enhance the logic by making sure you didn't log tickets for replies etc to ensure you are not duplicate logging incidents.

Comment: what I need is a call when a new tweet is tweeted on an account.